# js code need to be adjusted

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make all images in my website have "Fadein" effect when loading 
finished , so What is the problem with this code ? !

```
<img 
src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-M03SoTLlJ4k/Vfwvq2dz42I/AAAAAAAAD9I/o-xN8x6HL2Y/s1600-r/Untitled-1%2B%25281%2529.png"  id="image_id"/>
<style>
#image_id { 
opacity:0; 
transition:1s;
}
</style> 
<script>
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].addEventListener("load", imgfadein);
    };
function imgfadein() {
 x[i].style.opacity = "1";          
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, when the event handler runs, `i` is `x.length`, so `x[i]` is not set.

When the event listener function runs, `this` is the element that it was bound to. Use `this` instead of `x[i]`.

```
function imgfacein() {
    this.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Comment: It Works ^_^ 
Thanks <3 <3